# Android Bouncing Options View?

Tags: android, view

What is the name of the view that is used to display options in the latest android contacts app?

It's the one that after clicking on a contact picture slides in displays a few options in a horizontal line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are QuickActions. Google did not release any usable widget in the SDK for the moment, all you can do is try some third party implementations like http://www.londatiga.net/it/how-to-create-quickaction-dialog-in-android/